# Android App opens second instance when "launched" after back button pressed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, onbackpressed

**Short Version:**

An application I have been developing opens a second instance when it is "launched" after the back button has been pressed.

**Long Version:**

When the application is launched from the "home screen" it works fine- if the application is sent to the background by pressing the back arrow button, by pressing the circle button, or the square button to change to a different app - and then the application is resumed *through the multi-tasking menu* it works  perfectly - resuming exactly where it left off - not showing the splash screen again and most importantly not opening a second instance. *However* if the application is sent to the background and then *launched again* from the home screen a second instance of the application is created! The splash screen displays again and the main activity is displayed on the screen rather than the last activity that was on the users screen! This is obviously not the desired behavior and many solutions I have attempted do not work.

**Manifest:**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Settings_area"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDieXTCaFoIL0kJ_IM4UMBSQL3sNn92AWM" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
    <activity android:name=".Splash"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".aboutPageActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".turnOffFromNotification"
        android:noHistory="true"></activity>
</application>
```

**Edit:**
I have also attempted to replace `launchMode` in the application tag with `singleTask` and `singleInstance`.

Comment: I see your launch activity is `singleInstance`. Maybe thats resulting in this behavior.

Comment: Hello @Shaishav I have changed this to singleTop and singleTask - nothing seems to work! Do you have any other suggestions? Thank You!!

Comment: Try removing the launch mode. Any reason you need to run your activity in independent tasks?

Comment: @shaishav removing the launch mode does not work either .. no reason for independent tasks!

Comment: For the love of god get rid of the splash screen.

Answer (score 1):

> However if the application is sent to the background and then launched again from the home screen a second instance of the application is created! The splash screen displays again and the main activity is displayed on the screen rather than the last activity that was on the users screen!

This is an expected behavior of `Android`. The back button (*its default implementation*) is intended for a user to notify the system that he/she is done with the current `Activity` letting `Android` to destroy the `Activity`'s instance.

Note, such a behavior has nothing in common with the `android:launchMode` attribute.

> This is obviously not the desired behavior and many solutions I have attempted do not work.

You can't change it. It's a matter of a user who decided to leave the `Activity` and OS destroying the `Activity`'s instance no more needed.

Comment: Excellent thank you for the information! Do you know how I could bring the application to the front when they press the launcher icon rather than creating another instance?

Comment: If the instance is alive, pressing _"the launcher icon"_ will bring it to foreground, otherwise a new instance will be created. Instead of struggling with the scenario described I recommend to stick to the `Activity`'s [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle) callbacks and save the UI state in `onSaveInstanceState()`, then, when a user gets back to it, restore the state in `onRestoreInstanceState()`. By doing this the user would think like proceeding from the place he/she left the `Activity`.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for that information! It was very helpful! I will attempt to implement this solution now! Thank You!

Comment: can you please mention the source of the highlighted information?

Comment: @Wijay Sharma, you can easily check that on your own by logging Activity's `onDestroy()` method.

Comment: @Onik Thanks!  I am aware of it but is it documented somewhere?

Comment: @Wijay Sharma, not to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The situation was resolved by removing `android:launchMode="singleInstance">` from everywhere except the `<application>` tag. Apparently launch mode is best used when the goal is to create another task - which was not the desired behavior. Stock Android masked this behavior while the modified version of Android with Touchwiz did not.

Answer (score 0):

It saves the current Instance...(it will not destroy it).
when you open app again that time it will reopen the same Instance.

```
import android.view.KeyEvent;


public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true; // return
    }

    return false;
}
```